# random.seed does not work in Python 3.9.7 using Spyder

Tags: random

very simple program given below.

```
import random
random.random()
random.seed(3)
```

Gives error message as
File "C:\Users\admin\ram_stuff\Pythonprogs\random_passwd.py", line 11, in 
random.seed(3)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

I can go to cmd window in Windows10 and it runs fine.

```
C:\Users\admin>python
Python 3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import random
>>> random.random()
0.7989453624569347
>>> random.seed(3)
>>> random.random()
0.23796462709189137
```

Thank you.

Comment: i am bewildered. Very basic question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Somehow it "magically" went away after I closed Spyder and re-started it after deleting a whole bunch of older junk in the folder where my program lives.